# Were to print out data from API

Tags: android

I'm using Android Studio to make a crypto watcher app, a small school project and I've run into some problems. I want it to look something like this:

[CoinMarketCapApp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOwi6.jpg)

What should I use to do so?

I was thinking of using ListView, but I don't know how to add multiple String values to one line. I'm using fragments for activities. Any help on those problems is very appreciated!

My code:

[HomeFragment.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Whyg.jpg)

```html
package com.example.vartotojas.heycrypto;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = "HomeFragment";

    private TextView mTextViewResult;
    private RequestQueue mQueue;

    public Button refresh



    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_fragment,  container, false);
        return view;
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.coinListView);
        Button refresh = getView().findViewById(R.id.refresh);

        mQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        refresh = (Button) inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_home, container, false).findViewById(R.id.refresh);
        refresh.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        jsonParse()
    }

    private void jsonParse(){
        String url = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/";

        JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                for(int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++){
                    try {
                        JSONObject coin = response.getJSONObject(i);
                        String name= coin.getString("name");
                        String price = coin.getString("price");
                        String change24 = coin.getString("percent_change_24h");


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[activity_home.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqMYf.jpg)

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=". ">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:title="@string/app_name">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/tabItem"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Price" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/tabItem2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Favourite" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/tabItem3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Portfolio" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/tabItem2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Settings" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/refresh"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#9966ff"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:text="Refresh" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/coinListView"
        android:layout_marginTop="160dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using a ListView would be fine, but you're going to need to create a POJO to use as a model for each listItem. 
Use [this website](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) to create a good model class for your listItem.

And [here's the repo](https://github.com/pCulv/Popular_Movies_App) for one of my projects where I used Retrofit to pull data from a Movie database api and populated my `recylcerView` with data

If you plan on having a very long list of items I would say go with a `RecyclerView` instead.

Hope this helps!